# luke with datastax solr

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise, luke

I am trying to inspect solr indexes in DSE with luke. But getting the following error.

```
    Invalid directory at the location, 
    check console for more information. Last exception:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    An SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec with name 
    'dse460' does not exist.  
    You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI
    to your classpath.   
   The current classpath supports the following names: 
   [Lucene40, Lucene3x, Lucene41, Lucene42, Lucene45, 
    Lucene46, Lucene49, Lucene410, SimpleText, Appending]
```

Has anyone used luke with datastax solr indexes ?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, currently it's not possible to do with luke itself...

But you can inspect indices if you enable `LukeRequestHandler` in DSE Search's `solrconfig.xml`, like this

```
<requestHandler name="/admin/luke" class="solr.admin.LukeRequestHandler" />
```

After that you'll able to look inside index by accessing Solr web interface:

```
http://<server-ip>:8983/solr/<keyspace.table>/admin/luke
```

P.S. See [DSE Support article](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/207646946-HOW-TO-Setup-the-Luke-request-handler-in-Solr-to-examine-indexes) for more information about its usage.